# copy clicked link url to form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a login form (which opens in a jquery popup) that redirects after successful login back to the previous page.

I would like to populate a hidden redirect input within this login form with the value of the clicked link url, ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

     $("a.login").click(function() {

        if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            deselect();               
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
                $("#email").focus();
            });
        }
        return false;
    });


    $(".close").live('click', function() {
        deselect();
        return false;
    });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);
};
</script>

<form>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="clicked_link_url" />
</form>

<a href="clicked_link_url_1" class="login">Link 1</a>
<a href="clicked_link_url_2" class="login">Llink 2</a>
<a href="clicked_link_url_3" class="login">link 3</a>
```

So if the user clicks link 3, the popup form opens and it's hidden redirect url value will be "clicked_link_url3".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a.login").click(function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        deselect();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function () {
            $("#email").focus();
        });
    }

    // Set the input value
    $('input[name="redirect_url"]').val($(this).attr('href'));

    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks but not working for me, adding your full answer redirects back to previous page as per default behaviour and removing the e.preventDefault(); keeps me on the existing page. Original question edited to provide full .js code

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @Will.i.am, there was a missing closing ] in the code you provided, this is now working perfectly thanks very much! If you add the missing ] to your code I will mark the answer as correct. Thanks again